# angular 2 / bootstrap - variable length carousel using *ngFor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am trying to make a variable length carousel of images depending on how many images are contained in the array returned from backend call. This is what I have tried and there are a few problems with it, including that it is saying data-slide-to is not a property of li:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't bind to
>   'slide-to' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.
>   ("s="carousel-indicators"  *ngFor="let i of arrayRange">
>                 ]data-slide-to="{{i}}" ng-class='i == 0 ? "active" : ""'>

This is working when I manually insert my images using their indexes, but when I try this it does not work:

```
   <!--start carousel-->
   <div style="position: relative;" *ngIf="arrayRange != []">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators"  *ngFor="let i of arrayRange">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="{{i}}" ngClass="i == 0 ? 'active' : ''"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" *ngFor="let j of arrayRange; let k = index">
          <div ng-class="i == 0 ? 'item active' : 'item'">
            <img src={{imagesArray[k]}} alt="Event Image">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
   </div>
      <!--end carousel-->
```

Comment: You need to use property binding on all non-native element attributes. i.e. `[data-slide-to]="{{i}}"`.

Comment: didnt work sadly :(

Comment: what is the class/object structure of arrayRange and imagesArray

Comment: images array is an array of strings of urls, arrayRange is an array of integers from 0 to imagesArray.length

Answer (score 17):

Use

> [attr.data-slide-to]="i" ngClass="i == 0 ? 'active' : ''"

For example

```
<div style="position: relative;" *ngIf="arrayRange != []">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" *ngFor="let x of arrayRange;let i = index" [attr.data-slide-to]="i" ngClass="i == 0 ? 'active' : ''"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div *ngFor="let j of arrayRange; let k = index" [ngClass]="k == 0 ? 'item active' : 'item'">
                <img src={{imagesArray[k]}} alt="Event Image">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This worked for me :)

Comment: Awesome! This should be accepted as the solution aka [attr.data-slide-to]="i" instead of data-slide-to="{{i}}" solve the issue. Thx!

Comment: how to disable the carousel indicator if there is only one image in the array ? @daniel

Comment: Just put an *ngIf in the indicators, like *ngIf="arrayRange.lenght > 1"

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="position: relative;" *ngIf="arrayRange != []">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" *ngFor="let x of arrayRange;let i = index" data-slide-to="{{i}}" ngClass="i == 0 ? 'active' : ''"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div *ngFor="let j of arrayRange; let k = index" ng-class="k == 0 ? 'item active' : 'item'">
                <img src={{imagesArray[k]}} alt="Event Image">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

try this one. Mistake was ngFor should be inside the carousel-indicator and carousel-inner

Comment: still getting the same error after changing it to your code: Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'slide-to' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. ("icators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" *ngFor="let x of arrayRange;let i = index" [ERROR ->]data-slide-to="{{x}}" [ngClass]="{'active' : i == 0}"></li>
              </ol>

Comment: <li data-target="#myCarousel" *ngFor="let x of arrayRange;let i = index" data-slide-to="{{i}}" ngClass="i == 0 ? 'active' : ''"></li>

Comment: data-slide-to="{{i}}

Answer (score 1):

```
<li data-target="#myCarousel" *ngFor="let x of arrayRange;let i = index" 
data-slide-to="{{i}}" ngClass="i == 0 ? 'active' : ''"></li>
```

**should be changed to**

```
<li data-target="#myCarousel" *ngFor="let x of arrayRange;let i = index" 
attr.data-slide-to="{{i}}" ngClass="i == 0 ? 'active' : ''"></li>
```